# How to launch Office Web Add-in from Web Application hosted on-premises?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

We have built an Office Web Add-in for Excel, which renders a Web Application inside Excel Task pane.

The Web Application is hosted on-premises on IIS/ASP.NET.

We are able to launch the add-in within Excel **desktop**.

What network infrastructure / hosting is required to launch the add-in within Office 365 Excel **online** in a way that only allows users within the organisation to access the Web Application - would it require public IP?

From an authentication standpoint, we can restrict access to Web Application using SSO with our Azure AD tenant.

The add-in will be deployed and managed through centralized deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Office add-ins don't introduce any restrictions where and how to host the application. You just need to address the same-origin policy, read more about that in the [Addressing same-origin policy limitations in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/addressing-same-origin-policy-limitations) article.